# Oracle: find duplicate rows in select query

Tags: sql, oracle, count, duplicates

My SQL query returns results with 4 columns "A", "B", "C", "D".

Suppose the results are:

```
A    B    C    D
1    1    1    1
1    1    1    2
2    2    2    1
```

Is it possible to get the count of duplicate rows with columns "A", "B", "C" in each row.

e.g. the expected result is:

```
A    B    C    D    cnt
1    1    1    1    2
1    1    1    2    2
2    2    2    1    1
```

I tried using count(*) over. But it returns me the total number of rows returned by the query.
Another information is that in example I have mentioned only 3 columns based on which I need to check the count. But my actual query has such 8 columns. And number of rows in database are huge. So I think group by will not be a feasible option here.
Any hint is appreciable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe too late, but probably the count over as analytic function (aka window function) within oracle helps you. When I understand your request correctly, this should solve your problem :

```
create table sne_test(a number(1)
                 ,b number(1)
                 ,c number(1)
                 ,d number(1)
                 ,e number(1)
                 ,f number(1));

insert into sne_test values(1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into sne_test values(1,1,2,1,1,1);
insert into sne_test values(1,1,2,4,1,1);
insert into sne_test values(1,1,2,5,1,1);
insert into sne_test values(1,2,1,1,3,1);
insert into sne_test values(1,2,1,2,1,2);
insert into sne_test values(2,1,1,1,1,1);

commit;

 SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f, 
       count(*) over (PARTITION BY a,b,c)
  FROM sne_test;

 A  B  C  D  E  F AMOUNT
-- -- -- -- -- -- ------
 1  1  1  1  1  1      1
 1  1  2  4  1  1      3
 1  1  2  1  1  1      3
 1  1  2  5  1  1      3
 1  2  1  1  3  1      2
 1  2  1  2  1  2      2
 2  1  1  1  1  1      1
```

Comment: This also worked with Oracle 12c.  I can take a nap now.

Answer (score 6):

**To find duplicates you must group the data based on key column**

```
select 
  count(*)
  ,empno 
from 
  emp
group by
  empno
having
  count(*) > 1;
```

This allows you to aggregate by `empno` even when multiple records exist for each category (more than one).

Comment: Hello Surendra, I can not use group by as my select query fetches more that 20 columns and there are 8 such columns on whom i would have to use group by. Please refer to my comment on answer given by fthiella.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a subquery where you get the count of rows, grouped by A, B and C. And then you join this subquery again with your table (or with your query), like this:

```
select your_table.A, your_table.B, your_table.C, your_table.D, cnt
from
  your_table inner join
  (SELECT A, B, C, count(*) as cnt
   FROM your_table
   GROUP BY A, B, C) t
  on t.A = your_table.A
     and t.B = your_table.B
     and t.C = your_table.C
```

Comment: I can not use group by as my select query fetches more that 20 columns and there are 8 such columns on whom i would have to use group by. So I believe it will hit the performance.

Comment: @user613114 without `group by`.... well maybe you could use a query with variables (i know how to do it in mysql but not in oracle) but you still need to order by your 8 columns... and i don't believe it's faster than using a group by